# Storing Data in Application Support Folder in OS X

Tags: macos

I am writing a Cocoa application for OS X and need to store some data that will be used by the application after being downloaded. I understand that I should use the Application Support folder to do this (in Windows I use the AppData folder). But how do I start doing this because there is not a folder for my application in Application Support. All I would like to know is do I have to manually create a folder for my application in Application Support or does it get automatically created when the application is installed? Just a simple question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not get created automatically. Check out the documentation of the NSFileManager class. It provides all the methods to locate system folders and related manipulations.